# Equals not working in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've got some problems with simple knockout application.

Model:

```
function ContactListVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedContact = ko.observable("");
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.LoadItems = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Contacts/GetContactList/",
            type: "POST",
            data: { },
            success: function (data) {
               $.each(data.Contacts, function () {
                   self.contacts.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(this));
               });

               if (self.selectedContact() == "") {
                   var data = new Object();
                   data.ID = self.contacts()[0].ID;

                   self.selectContact(data, null);
               }
            }
        });
    }

    self.LoadItems();

    self.selectContact = function (data, event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Contacts/GetContact/",
            type: "POST",
            data: { ID: data.ID },
            success: function (data) {
                self.selectedContact(ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Contact));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So generaly I have a list of contacts with very basic info and a full model of the selected contact. The selected contact should be marked on the list with different css class:

```
<ul class="contact-list">
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'item-template', foreach: contacts() } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <script id="item-template" type="text/html">
        <li class="item" data-bind="click: $root.selectContact, css: { selected: $root.selectedContact().ID == ID() }">
            <span class="contact-name" data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            <span class="contact-name" data-bind="text: $root.selectedContact().ID"></span>
            <span class="contact-name" data-bind="text: ID()"></span>
        </li>
    </script>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately the statement css: { selected: $root.selectedContact().ID == ID() } is not working. None of the items is selected. What is more few lines below where I bind these values to spans they appear equal on the screen. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pUHEf/

The problem was that before you selected a contact selectedContact() was empty, therefore had no method ID.  You need to put an additional statement into your logic.

```
<script id="item-template" type="text/html">
        <li class="item" data-bind="click: $root.selectContact, css: { selected: $root.selectedContact() ? $root.selectedContact().ID() === ID() : false }">
            <span class="contact-name" data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            <span class="contact-name" data-bind="text: $root.selectedContact().ID"></span>
            <span class="contact-name" data-bind="text: ID()"></span>
        </li>
</script>
```

This works, check the fiddle.  A basic explanation -

The selected class will be applied if the following logic is true (in my own language)

```
if ($root.selectedContact() !== (undefined or null))
{
    if ($root.selectedContact().ID() === ID())
    {
        set class = selected;
    }
    else { don't set a class }
}
else { don't set a class }
```

Comment: Unfortunately now I receive "Message: Object  has no method 'ID'", is it possible that the bindings in the view (template) are made prior to the setting of selectedContact in my model? If so how should it be done?

Comment: Ah, then your ID is not an observable property.  I just looked back at where you are assigning that property and indeed it is not observable.  Can you let me know whether the contact is an observable after it is mapped?  If you console.log selectedContact does it show ID as being a function or just a value?

Comment: It looks like ID is a function - weird.
`ID: function observable()`